# angularjs: cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm developing a web app with AngularJS (with npm, bower, and grunt to build the app). The main structure is to use a separate folder for each module under the 'app' folder. Now I have a new module which needs to use service, so I created a different folder 'common' under 'src' (in parallel with 'app') and put the service js files inside. I have injected the dependencies in the js file which uses the service, but when I ran the app I got this error message: **cannot read property 'module' of undefined**. The 'module' refers to the definition inside the service file, like this:

```
angular.module('setup-service', _DEPENDENCIES).
    factory('SetupService', function($rootScope, $http, $timeout) {...}
```

The header of the file is like this:

```
(function(angular, kendo) {
    'use strict';
    ...
```

So I suppose the syntax is correct right? What could be the reason for the error?

EDIT: before the new module added in, all the previous modules worked fine.

Comment: did you call the iife with angular object? as argument
(function(angular){})(angular)?? also is _DEPENDENCIES and array?

Comment: Could You pls, include grunt task for compiling all the JS? As is @Tushar saying, it may be that some files are not included when they are supposed to.

Comment: `angular` is undefined here. please check console angularjs file is loading correctly or not ? have you added it to your html ? or check any other error might be affecting

Comment: @Richards, https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f90965f-2f5e-47ba-b337-ad55f95c5b61?SRC=VSIDE . It is a sample Angular app and it uses multiple modules.

Comment: ok adding (angular) to the end of file solves the problem (yeah follow iife). But now the error is: Module Angular is not available. maybe I should put the question in this way: when I add in a new directory with service files, how should I modify the grunt file?